# Android - Customizing ads

Tags: android, ads

I have developed an Android App and want to add some custom ads in it. I know that I can make a fragment and attach it to the layout but what about changing the ads frequently?
For e.g. I have two Images (of ads) and want to change every of them in 5 minutes. How can I do that?
Also I do not have any idea to put interstitial ads. Any help is appreciated. I am a beginner in this field

Answer (score 0):

To change the time of the ads you must do it directly from your **provider** console,
if you are using **Admob** you can do it from there by selecting your *Ad unit* and going into the **refresh** **rate** option,

also consider the following, this is from the support page of admob

The **refresh rate** determines how often a new ad impression is generated. You can choose not to refresh ads or to refresh every **30** to **120** seconds. We recommended that you have ads persist for **60** seconds or longer, depending on the functionality of your application. Our internal tests have shown that this ensures users have enough time to engage with ads, providing the best performance for both advertisers and publishers. Furthermore, these tests have shown that refreshing ads more often can hurt fill rate for our publishers.

If your app is automatically refreshing ads, make sure ad requests are not made when the screen is off. Also, if users navigate to and from pages with ads in an application over a short period of time, a new ad request should not be made sooner than the **recommended** 60 second rate.

You can refer to more info [here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6128738?hl=en)

Comment: I am not using Admob as it can't be use in eclipse according to it's new rules. I want to create my own ads.